# Can't populate Combobox from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

I seem to be having trouble populating a Combo box from my SQL server.

For reasons I have changed the server IP for this example and username and password, but I have debugged that bit and I know it is connecting to the server.

Also where it says

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It has rows!!");
}
```

it pulls through as it has rows but the combo box is still empty.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.DataSource = "123.456.789.101";
builder.InitialCatalog = "DiscoverThePlanet";
builder.UserID = "MadeupUser";
builder.Password = "MadeupPass";

string connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;    
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes");
    SqlDataReader reader;

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
    dt.Columns.Add("NoteID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("NoteName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Note", typeof(string));

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It has rows!!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It doesn't have rows :(");
    }

    //foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
    //{
    //    foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
    //    {
    //        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(item);
    //    }
    //}

    noteNamesList.DataContext = dt;
    noteNamesList.SelectedValue = "NoteID";
    noteNamesList.DisplayMemberPath = "NoteName";    
    dt.Load(reader);    
    conn.Close();
 }
```

Anything I have missed or any help will be much appreciated.

Combo box is named: noteNamesList

Answer (score 1):

You create a datatable, you read results from your database, but you never load the query results to your datatable before you bind it to the control.

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(reader);

//there is no reason to add columns to your datatable.  you can remove these lines:
//dt.Columns.Add("NoteID", typeof(string));
//dt.Columns.Add("NoteName", typeof(string));
//dt.Columns.Add("Note", typeof(string));
```

Comment: Oh ok, i didn't even realise that. Thanks

Comment: @Bridge - but that's after the attempt to bind the datatable to the list control.  The datatable must be loaded BEFORE it's bound to the control.

Comment: No need to tell me - you hadn't told OP that when I wrote it :)

Comment: @devlincarnate unfortunately its still not populating the combobox

Comment: @LukeLitherland - put a breakpoint after the line where you load the datatable, and inspect the content of the datatable in debug mode.  Are the list items there that you expect to see?  Have you configured the list so that it knows what column is the Text and what column is the Value?

Comment: @devlincarnate I shall try that tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @devlincarnate Hi i just tried this and in the 'Locals' tab in debug mode my DataTable (dt) has a value of {} does this mean there is nothing in there, and is this classing these brackets as a row?

Comment: @LukeLitherland - you need to right click on the {} and view the results in the DataTable Visualizer.  Or, put in a line that gives you the count of rows in your datatable:  `var test = dt.Rows.Count;` and put a breakpoint on that line to verify test contains the number you expect.

Comment: @devlincarnate Hi devlin, all sorted, please see me answer i posted, hopefully it helps others with the same issue. PS Thanks for all the help and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "SelectedValuePath" instead of "SelectedValue". I'm not sure if this will fix it but I had a similar error a while back and it fixed mine.

Comment: Hmm, this hasn't made a difference :(

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on the other answer but maybe try loading your DataTable before assigning your ComboBox values? Maybe moving it up before the "reader" initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with a couple of things.

First being instead of using `noteNamesList.DataContext = dt;`

I used `noteNamesList.ItemSource = dt.DefaultView;`

Also in here:

```
    noteNamesList.DataContext = dt;
    noteNamesList.SelectedValue = "NoteID";
    noteNamesList.DisplayMemberPath = "NoteName";    
    dt.Load(reader);    
    conn.Close();
```

I moved the: `dt.Load(reader);` up so its just below:

```
    dt.Columns.Add("NoteID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("NoteName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Note", typeof(string));
```

So its like this:

```
    dt.Columns.Add("NoteID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("NoteName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Note", typeof(string));
    dt.Load(reader);
```

Lastly i made sure that the

```
noteNamesList.ItemSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

was called AFTER this:

```
    noteNamesList.SelectedValue = "NoteID";
    noteNamesList.DisplayMemberPath = "NoteName";
```

Hopefully this helps others with the same Issue.